# How can I load a data frame saved in pandas as an HDF5 file in R without losing integers larger than 32 bit?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, hdfs

I'm getting this warning message when I try to load data frame saved in pandas as an HDF5 file in R:

> Warning message: In H5Dread(h5dataset = h5dataset, h5spaceFile =
>   h5spaceFile, h5spaceMem = h5spaceMem,  :   NAs produced by integer
>   overflow while converting 64-bit integer or unsigned 32-bit integer
>   from HDF5 to a 32-bit integer in R. Choose bit64conversion='bit64' or
>   bit64conversion='double' to avoid data loss and see the vignette
>   'rhdf5' for more details about 64-bit integers.

For example, if I create HDF5 file in pandas with:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[1234567001,1234515616515167005],
    'X2':[23.88,23.96]
},columns=['time','X2'])

store = pd.HDFStore('a.hdf5')
store['df'] =  frame
store.close()
print(frame)
```

which returns:

```
                  time     X2
0           1234567001  23.88
1  1234515616515167005  23.96
```

and try to load it in R:

```
#source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite("rhdf5")
library(rhdf5)

loadhdf5data <- function(h5File) {
  # Function taken from [How can I load a data frame saved in pandas as an HDF5 file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45024089/395857)
  listing <- h5ls(h5File)
  # Find all data nodes, values are stored in *_values and corresponding column
  # titles in *_items
  data_nodes <- grep("_values", listing$name)
  name_nodes <- grep("_items", listing$name)

  data_paths = paste(listing$group[data_nodes], listing$name[data_nodes], sep = "/")
  name_paths = paste(listing$group[name_nodes], listing$name[name_nodes], sep = "/")

  columns = list()
  for (idx in seq(data_paths)) {
    print(idx)
    data <- data.frame(t(h5read(h5File, data_paths[idx])))
    names <- t(h5read(h5File, name_paths[idx],  bit64conversion='bit64'))
    #names <- t(h5read(h5File, name_paths[idx],  bit64conversion='double'))
    entry <- data.frame(data)
    colnames(entry) <- names
    columns <- append(columns, entry)
  }

  data <- data.frame(columns)

  return(data)
}

frame  = loadhdf5data("a.hdf5")
```

I get this warning message:

```
> frame = loadhdf5data("a.hdf5")
[1] 1
[1] 2
Warning message:
In H5Dread(h5dataset = h5dataset, h5spaceFile = h5spaceFile, h5spaceMem = h5spaceMem,  :
  NAs produced by integer overflow while converting 64-bit integer or unsigned 32-bit integer from HDF5 to a 32-bit integer in R. Choose bit64conversion='bit64' or bit64conversion='double' to avoid data loss and see the vignette 'rhdf5' for more details about 64-bit integers.
```

and I can see that one of the time values became NA:

```
> frame
     X2       time
1 23.88 1234567001
2 23.96         NA
```

How can I fix this issue? Choosing `bit64conversion='bit64'` or `bit64conversion='double'` doesn't change anything.

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HDF5 Dataset Interface's documentation](https://rdrr.io/github/Bioconductor-mirror/rhdf5/man/H5D.html) says:

> bit64conversion: Defines, how 64-bit integers are converted. Internally, R does not support 64-bit integers. All integers in R are 32-bit integers. By setting bit64conversion='int', a coercing to 32-bit integers is enforced, with the risc of data loss, but with the insurance that numbers are represented as integers. bit64conversion='double' coerces the 64-bit integers to floating point numbers. doubles can represent integers with up to 54-bits, but they are not represented as integer values anymore. For larger numbers there is again a data loss. bit64conversion='bit64' is recommended way of coercing. It represents the 64-bit integers as objects of class 'integer64' as defined in the package 'bit64'. Make sure that you have installed 'bit64'. The datatype 'integer64' is not part of base R, but defined in an external package. This can produce unexpected behaviour when working with the data.

You should therefore install bit64 (`install.packages("bit64")`) and load it (`library(bit64)`). You can check that `integer64` is loaded:

```
> integer64
Function (length = 0) 
{
    ret <- double(length)
    oldClass(ret) <- "integer64"
    ret
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001a7a95f0>
<environment: namespace :it64>
```

Now you can run:

```
library(bit64)
library(rhdf5)
loadhdf5data <- function(h5File) {

  listing <- h5ls(h5File)
  # Find all data nodes, values are stored in *_values and corresponding column
  # titles in *_items
  data_nodes <- grep("_values", listing$name)
  name_nodes <- grep("_items", listing$name)

  data_paths = paste(listing$group[data_nodes], listing$name[data_nodes], sep = "/")
  name_paths = paste(listing$group[name_nodes], listing$name[name_nodes], sep = "/")

  columns = list()
  for (idx in seq(data_paths)) {
    print(idx)
    data <- data.frame(t(h5read(h5File, data_paths[idx],  bit64conversion='bit64')))
    names <- t(h5read(h5File, name_paths[idx],  bit64conversion='bit64'))
    entry <- data.frame(data)
    colnames(entry) <- names
    columns <- append(columns, entry)
  }

  data <- data.frame(columns)

  return(data)
}


frame = loadhdf5data("a.hdf5")
```

which gives:

```
> frame
     X2                time
1 23.88          1234567001
2 23.96 1234515616515167005
```